# How safe to move some system folders into ram?

Tags: 12.10, performance, directory, system, tweak

Here is my pc specs

[image]

Based [on this tutorial](http://turriebuntu.wordpress.com/ubuntu-pages/general-ubuntu-pages/moving-temporary-files-to-memory-a-good-idea-if-youre-using-a-ssd/) I made following changeds to fstab

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=0755 0 0 
tmpfs /var/log/apt tmpfs defaults,noatime 0 0
```

Now I got some question:

1. Will it increase my system's performance?
2. How safe it is for my pc?
3. May some apps like dvd burning tool crash because of big temp space requirement? (My SWAP area is 8 gb as RAM)

Thx in advance for wasting your time and trying to help

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Is your laptop storage slow at the moment? Are you using an SSD? If so, trying to prevent wear and did you enable TRIM for example? Really... we need so much more information. Just running "because" is a big no-no for what I see in that "tutorial".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No, don't run this.

Moving `/var/log` onto ephemeral storage is very likely to get you into basic trouble. You'll lose all log files across reboots, including the directories packages are expected to be there. If for example `/var/log/cups/` does not exists, you'll probably first have to re-create the directory before you can print anything and Cups can't even burp the errors in the meantime...

`/var/log/apt` on another `tmpfs` inside one? This does not make sense.

About `/var/tmp` and `/tmp`, I find [this](http://linuxers.org/article/differences-between-tmp-and-vartmp) a nice explanation:

> Since in most of the default installations the `/tmp` folder will be cleaned in every reboot. This is where `/var/tmp` comes in to play. Here, applications can expect their data to be preserved between reboots. In other words, data stored here is more persistent than `/tmp`.

So, stuff will probably break. Applications rely on the persistence of `/var/tmp`.

#### Common sense

Don't just do stuff people or blog posters recommend you to do.

Comment: Thx for anwer. I upvoted your answer, but there was nothing with my question to downvote.

Comment: @TuralTeyyubogluAliyev Yes, there is. 1) Not enough information on what you're trying to accomplish. 2) Dumping a list of commands from a random website, without any research effort. 3) two out of three questions can only be answered by yourself (too many factors into play).